# C compiler ignore second argument

Tags: c

I am trying to write a wrapper for a library and I'm attempting to get the compiler to ignore the second argument (for lack of a better phrase) when compiling.

I would like to get this to happen in Rust, but C would be fine as well.

Just as an example, suppose I have this C code

```
void func(int a, int b, int c) {
    // ... 
}
```

The calling convention for this in assembly would be arg 0 to `rdi`, arg 1 to `rsi`, arg 2 to `rdx`, arg 3 to `rcx`, arg 4 to `r8`, arg 5 to `r9`, and the rest to the stack.

I want to tell the compiler to put arg 0 in `rdi` and arg 1 in `rdx`, essentially skipping `rsi`. This is just for this particular calling convention.

The library I am calling against uses the second argument as an offset to a jump table essentially, but my wrapper will handle this internally.

My code would essentially look like

`wrapper(arg0, arg1, arg2, ...)` -> `api(arg1, <static offset>, arg1, arg2, ...)`

I want to try to do this without having to manually shift over each argument since the API call is of indefinite arity and shifting stuff into the stack could prove to be an issue. Also, I am trying to make cross compilable, so this particular calling convention may not always be used.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I would try `void func(int a, int space, int b, int c) { (void)space; // ... }` in c. Its the common syntax for an unused variable that still has to be in the function.

Comment: @LambdaBeta Would that allow me to call that function like `func(1,2,3)` with space being skipped? Is that standard C or is that a Compiler extension?

Comment: That's just extension of how the language works. However you would still have to call `func(1,0 /* for spacing */, 2, 3)`. I am not sure if there is a standard way to actually specify calling convention. I have never actually looked into it.

Comment: @LambdaBeta I think I am trying to do the opposite of what you are suggesting. My wrapper function will just pass all the arguments through with no changes, except for the second argument which will be determined at runtime. So essentially I am calling an n argument function with only n-1 arguments, where the 2nd argument is implied and does not need to be specified in the function call.

Comment: I don't think there is a standard way to do that. I did compile a tiny test file `int func(int a, int space, int b, int c) { (void)space; return a + b - c; } int main() { return func(1,0,1,1); }` and checked the assembly and it does indeed generate `... movl $1, %ecx movl $1, %edx movl $0, %esi movl $1, %edi call func ...` but you do have to actually specify it.

Comment: @LambdaBeta I am testing as well. I had success with making a struct that is 2 size_t elements in size, only specifying the first (a) and using the whole struct as the first arg. This seemed to work. I will try and figure out the best way to incorporate this.

Comment: I've edited out the minor aspects of this question that touch on Rust. Any answer you get is going to be drastically different between languages (I'd actually assume any answer will be *compiler* specific, if it's even possible without writing assembly). If you get an answer and want to know the Rust equivalent, I think it would be highly welcome for you to ask a *second* question, including all the interesting details, and *also* provide a link back here.

Comment: Your API is not of infinite arity because your computer does not have infinite memory. Find out what arity it actually is and code to that. For example, is twenty enough?